# Ruby On Rails How to Copy local Postgres db to Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I tried this on RubyMine Terminal:

```
heroku pg:push ror_development postgres://budobqbtsbzmlx:hUNYKkaMap-cExovtPJat4ajPm@ec2-54-217-208-1 58.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/dbhsnsvf36h8tu
```

But its return me error:

> Unknown database: postgres://budobqbtsbzmlx:hUNYKkaMap-cExovtPJat4ajPm@ec2-54-217-208-158.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.
>   com:5432/dbhsnsvf36h8tu. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ONYX_URL

and also this error:

> Connecting to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ONYX_URL (DATABASE_URL)
>   'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Can somebody show detail sample of doing this action on windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states that you should use the environment variables rather than explicit names. [The documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push) states you should do something like:
`heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ONYX`

That said, I've never used this technique but did manage to successfully push my local db to heroku postgresql using [this procedure](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import-to-heroku-postgres).

Here's the short version:

1. install pgbackups:
   `heroku addons:add pgbackups`
2. backup your local db:
   `pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U <user> <dbname> > local_pg.dump`
3. upload this file to a web server (I use S3 or dropbox). Let's assume `http://www.dropbox.com/me/local_pg.dump`
4. now restore into your heroky db:
   `heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'http://www.dropbox.com/me/local_pg.dump'`